# Reading a csv file with random generated values into Java

Tags: java, csv

First of all I generated a random list of values using the Rand() formula in Excel and converted the list to a Csv file format, when reading this csv in Java, i get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
at SatelliteView.UrlSatelliteImage.main(UrlSatelliteImage.java:60)
```

Im not sure how to resolve this error as any other list that i have created works fine
heres the code that normally works:

File file = new File(csvFile);// creates a file to enable us to read contents of location file

```
    try {           
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
        sc.useDelimiter("\n"); 
        sc.next(); // ignores header row            
        while (sc.hasNext()) {  // loops through csv
            String csvRows = sc.next(); // streams next line
            String[] csvLocations = csvRows.split(",");                                 

            String latitude = csvLocations[0];              
            double x = Double.parseDouble(latitude);                
        String longitude = csvLocations[1];
            double y = Double.parseDouble(longitude);

            System.out.println(csvLocations[0] + " " + csvLocations[1]);            
        }
        sc.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
```

Now, the output reads and prints off all the values required but with the exception error. The code itself works fine with normal csv file values that were manually typed in but Im not sure if using the Rand() formula to generate these values has also created something new that needs to be omitted somehow. Anybody any ideas? thank you in advance.

Comment: java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String is the key

Comment: *"any ideas?"* Yes. **Look at the file!!!** --- Since you don't print values from `csvLocations` until *after* you try parsing, the error is on the *next* line in the file. The file obviously doesn't contain what you think it does.

Comment: yeah just noticed that @Andreas

Comment: *Unrelated:* `Scanner` is slow. If you just want to read lines, use a `BufferedReader` and the `readLine()` method. Don't use `Scanner` for reading lines from a file.

Comment: perhaps checking csvRows before trying to split it apart will help

Comment: ok, I'll see about using the BufferedReader etc instead. Ive been thinking that the problem was something else.thank you loads for the help guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error states `java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String` and `at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(Unknown Source)`

So that means you are trying to parse an `empty String` into a `Double`

This appends either here

```
double x = Double.parseDouble(latitude);
```

or here

```
double y = Double.parseDouble(longitude);
```

So basically the string you are reading probably does not contain any coordinates (probably en empty line). Change your `while` loop to this, it might work. (I also added more logs so you can see what it happening)

```
while (sc.hasNext()) {  // loops through csv

    String csvRows = sc.next();
    // print out the line value to see what we are dealing with
    System.out.println("rawTextValue: " + csvRows);            

    // if the line is not empty
    if(!csvRows.isEmpty()) {

        String[] csvLocations = csvRows.split(",");                                 
        System.out.println(csvLocations[0] + " " + csvLocations[1]);            

        String latitude = csvLocations[0];
        double x = Double.parseDouble(latitude);                
        System.out.println("x: " + x);            

        String longitude = csvLocations[1];
        double y = Double.parseDouble(longitude);
        System.out.println("y: " + y);            
    }
 }
```

Comment: thats great help Bentaye, it seems to have eventually resolved the exception error, my understanding is that the If statement closes out of the while loop when the row returns with no values. Makes sense now, thank you very much.